# visual basic in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need your help please
I have created a module into Microsoft Excel and I wrote this code .
I want to convert numbers to words
for example if I enter number 5 inside a cell in worksheet , I want to show this result "five syrian pounds " by using the new Function which I called ( Number_To_Words )
but the result is 0 when I used the function
What is the Wrong in this Code ???

```
Function TheOnes(number As Integer)
suffix1 As String
suffix2 As String
suffix1 = "one syrian pound"
suffix2 = "syrain pounds"
Select Case number
Case 1: TheOnes = suffix1
Case 2: TheOnes = " Two " + suffix2
Case 3: TheOnes = " Three " + suffix2
Case 4: TheOnes = " Four " + suffix2
Case 5: TheOnes = " Five " + suffix2
Case 6: TheOnes = " Six " + suffix2
Case 7: TheOnes = " Seven " + suffix2
Case 8: TheOnes = " Eight " + suffix2
Case 9: TheOnes = " Nine " + suffix2
End Select
End Function
Function Number_To_Words(number As Integer)
Select Case Len(number)
Case 1: Number_To_Words = TheOnes(number)
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: What's the point of **TWO** `Select Case`???

Comment: He could end up adding, for example, Words to numbers. Then he could then process a word to a number and a number to a word. Just speculating his thought.

Comment: How high a number are you hoping to convert?  From what I can see you've got `Select Case Number` and then start running through the numbers.  From what I can tell it needs one Case statement for each different number you could pass it?  Also - is _syrain_ some kind of precipitation?

Comment: Not wanting to figure it out for myself.... these links will do the job.  https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/convert-numbers-currency-to-words-with-excel-vba.  Converted _1978.25_ to _One Thousand Nine Hundred Seventy Eight syrian pounds and Twenty Five syrian cents_

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook , i hope to reach to 999,999,999 and the code which i wrote in my question is just a part , there are more functions for helping the convertion operation , i mean When the number is composed of two position, the function ( TheTens) will be used in the second select in Number_To_Words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declarations for suffix1 and suffix2 are missing the `DIM` command:

```
Dim suffix1 As String
Dim suffix2 As String
```

Also, you need to convert the value in the cell to a string before testing the length in **Number_To_Words** with `LEN`.

Try changing the test to:

```
Select Case Len(CStr(number))
```

Also, check your spelling of "syrian" in suffix2.

---

**EDIT**

You could replace your *TheOnes* function with the following slightly neater alternative:

```
Function TheOnes(number As Integer)
    Dim suffix
    suffix = Array(" Zero", " One", " Two", " Three", " Four", " Five", " Six", " Seven", " Eight", " Nine")
    TheOnes = suffix(number)
    TheOnes = TheOnes & " syrian pound"
    If number > 1 Then TheOnes = TheOnes & "s"
End Function
```

Comment: Currently you'd need `Case 125: TheOnes = " one hundred and twenty five " + suffix2`.  Check the link on my comment on your original question.

Comment: how can I know the index of a text or number in VBA language , for example i have got number 125 and i need to test the hundreds & the tens & the ones so i can make my function more powerful

Comment: I suggest documentation, this is the best way to learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/string-functions

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the length of an integer in you second select case. Length would be used for getting the size of an array for example. I believe the following will help you in in your future endeavors. I would also consider properly indenting your work and declaring variables using `Dim`. This can be helpful in determining a variables data type on declaration, however specifying works as well when using `Option Explicit Off`.

```
 Function TheOnes(number As Integer)
        Dim suffix1 As String
        Dim suffix2 As String
        suffix1 = "one syrian pound"
        suffix2 = "syrain pounds"
        Select Case number
            Case 1 : TheOnes = suffix1
            Case 2 : TheOnes = " Two " + suffix2
            Case 3 : TheOnes = " Three " + suffix2
            Case 4 : TheOnes = " Four " + suffix2
            Case 5 : TheOnes = " Five " + suffix2
            Case 6 : TheOnes = " Six " + suffix2
            Case 7 : TheOnes = " Seven " + suffix2
            Case 8 : TheOnes = " Eight " + suffix2
            Case 9 : TheOnes = " Nine " + suffix2
        End Select
    End Function

    Function Number_To_Words(number As Integer)
        Select Case number
            Case 1 : Number_To_Words = TheOnes(number)
        End Select
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of `Number_To_Words` and call `TheOnes` directly.